# Retrieve variable from another class and send to another scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, scene, unityscript

Sorry for asking a noob question, but I have never used c# in Unity, only unityscript.

Basically I have a `public int score` variable stored in `Players` Class.

I need to retrieve it in the following method:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if(c.tag == "PlayerCollision")
    {
        if(!c.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().isDead)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
            //Load next scene
        }
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the `score` variable in this method below and send the variable to the next scene? (In unity script I had to do something like `Application.LoadLevel(1);` after of course building the scene as levels. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you already got useful answers to your question, but just want to clarify one thing you seem to be misunderstanding: Application.LoadLevel() is the same command regardless of programming language, and that command has nothing to do with persisting variables between scenes, that is the command to *change* scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to make the variable `static`. Eg.

```
public static int score
```

Then you could access it any time using `Players.score`. There are other approaches such as singletons, but I think that would be overkill.

If you have several variables like this, you could decouple them into a helper class and access them all from there.

Answer (score 1):

Set the script to an object and set this in the script:

void Awake () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
}

Your object pass all scenes and you can give their variables these values you need in the other scenes.